# White wallpaper after 13.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, desktop-background, 13.04

I recently upgraded to 13.04 but now my wallpaper is missing, I only have a white background although everything seems to be working (icons, etc.). I tried to change the "Have file manager handle the desktop" on Tweak Tool and directly in gconf with success.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

The only time I see the configured wallpaper is when the screen is locked.

[image]

Comment: Sounds the same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/285111/no-wallpaper-after-installing-blueman-on-13-04  - if so, this is a bug.

Comment: Try this one ^^